# Starter for fluorescent light fell in water

Tags: lighting

I was fiddling around with the starter switch for the fluorescent light and it fell into water.

Will it still work after it dries? What kind of damage can there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the water is clean it will work. The main risk is that some amount of water will remain.

One solution is to fill a bucket with alcohol then dunk it in the bucket. The evaporation of the alcohol will take all the water with it and make it nice and dry. You can also sit it in the bright sun for a few days.

Comment: Nice answer. The water wasn't really all that clean so I'll buy a new one to be sure.